# switch statement not working maybe misunderstanding

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

This should be easy but maybe im confusing how switch statements work. I have a data attribute associated with a list item. When you click the list item I pass the data attribute number to the switch which should run the function if the data attribute and the switch are equal. Isn't this how it works? Here the numbers should match up yet im getting the default every-time. However if i hard code the correct number it functions. Why is this? Thanks Stack,

**HTML:**

```
        <ul class="carousel_indicators">
        <li class = "anchor">First Step</li>
            <li class = " nav_li sub_li active" data-pointer-slide = "10" data-target="#option-carousel" data-slide-to="0">Slider</li>
            <li class = "nav_li sub_li" data-pointer-slide = "21" data-target="#option-carousel" data-slide-to="1">Social Hub</li>
        <li class = "nav_li" data-pointer-slide = "32" data-target="#option-carousel" data-slide-to="2">The Spirit</li>
        <li class = "nav_li" data-pointer-slide = "44" data-target="#option-carousel" data-slide-to="3">Elephant People</li>
        <li class = "nav_li" data-pointer-slide = "55" data-target="#option-carousel" data-slide-to="4">Elephant Room</li>
        <li class = "nav_li" data-pointer-slide = "65" data-target="#option-carousel" data-slide-to="5">Features</li>
        <li class = "nav_li" data-pointer-slide = "76" data-target="#option-carousel" data-slide-to="6">Spirit Award</li>
        <li class = "nav_li"><a href = "{{'auth/logout'}}">Logout</a></li>
        <div class = "red_pointer"></div>
      </ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $('.nav_li').click(function(){
      var $listItem = $(this);
      var $point = $('.red_pointer');
      var $rePoint = $listItem.attr('data-pointer-slide');
        console.log($rePoint);
    switch ($rePoint) {
        case 10:
            $point.animate({
               top: '10%'
            },1000);
            break;
        case 21:
            $point.animate({
                top: '21%'
            }, 1000);
            break;
        case 32:
            $point.animate({
                top: '32%'
            }, 1000);
            break;
        case 44:
            $point.animate({
                top: '44%'
            }, 1000);
            break;
        case 55:
            $point.animate({
                top: '55%'
            }, 1000);
            break;
        case 65:
            $point.animate({
                top: '65%'
            }, 1000);
            break;
        case 76:
            $point.animate({
                top: '76%'
            }, 1000);
            break;
        default:
            console.log($rePoint);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$repoint` is a string. You're comparing it with numbers, and `switch` uses strict equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why there is extra bracket at the `switch ($rePoint))` - it should be `switch ($rePoint)`

Also try comparing the variable with strings not numbers.

Comment: so setting the data attribute to a number still brings back a string?

Comment: As you can see here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ - it returns String

Comment: Cool thanks didn't know that.